# Getting camera to always return a snapped photo right side up?

Tags: android, rotation, orientation, bmp

The format of my app is all in portrait mode.  Oddly, when I snap a photo in portrait mode, it is displayed on the ImageView sideways (like it was snapped in landscape)...the only way it is displayed right side up is if I snap the pic in landscape mode.

Anyone know of a simple workaround that displays the photo ride side up, regardless of the camera's orientation?  I can easily provide my code if anyone needs to take a look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code I used onActivityResult() in my activity.  The intent returned was for picking an image of the type image/*.  Works well for me!

```
Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
int orientation = -1;
if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
    orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
}  
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(orientation);
```

Comment: Clever! I have a solution to this that examines EXIF tags... this is a lot neater. (Although why BitmapFactory.decodeBitmap() doesnt respect JPEG orientation is surely the real problem).

Comment: Thanks man. I tried to use Exif tags but it was always 0 when checking the image uri returned from the intent.